# Class not found exception while running sqoop: org/apache/sqoop/Sqoop

Tags: java, hadoop, installation, classpath, sqoop

I 've installed sqoop on a machine 
(sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-1.0.0.tar.gz from http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.4/).
 When I try to run "$SQOOP_HOME/sqoop help"
or any other command for that matter,

I am receiving the following error:

> Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/sqoop/Sqoop Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Could not find the main class: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.  Program will exit.

I tried installing sqoop in other machines and it worked fine. But not in one particular machine I want :( I've set hadoop home path and also have sqoop home in classpath.

Could someone let me know where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set Sqoop home in classpath set sqoop lib in classpath as follow:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$SQOOP_HOME/lib
```